# coloring transparent status bar

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to colour the status bar in my app without colouring the whole background of the activity. I thought I could use the following code to create an amber bar and status with an offwhite activity. However, the offwhite overrides the amber and colours the status white too

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/amber500">

    <!-- colour the bar and status amber -->

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".GuestbookActivity"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/offwhite">

        <!-- main UI in here on offwhite backgroud -->
```

This is the effect I want in the status but I dont want the amber background thats showing here when the list does not fill the space. This does not have the very last line of code above applied

[image]

This is what happens in another activity when I add the very last line i.e. add an offwhite background to the inner layout

[image]

Comment: Could you please show some Java code?

Comment: I dont think there is any relevant java code as all tbis is hard coded in the view

Comment: Where are you applying that layout?

Comment: I have added some screenshots above. The plan would be to apply this to multiple layouts if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use [systembartint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint). This gave the results I wanted without adding any UI overdraw

Answer (score 0):

I've never had any success with fitsSystemWindows. It seems to never work right for me, especially if I have the `windowTranslucentNavigation` or `windowTranslucentStatus` flag set. As such, you'll have to set padding on the inner white div manually.

An example follows:

```
package com.example.myapp2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int topPadding = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            topPadding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }

        int bottomPadding = 0;
        resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            bottomPadding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }


     findViewById(R.id.background).setPadding(0, topPadding, 0, bottomPadding);
    }
}
```

And the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/background"
              android:background="#FF0000"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        >

    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```